# Unable to import urllib3 in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib3

I am using python 3.5.2.

When I try to install `urllib3`, I am getting the below error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'urllib3'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urllib3` is not a default module.

Install it using:

```
pip install urllib3
```

References:

1. https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/